# How do I use a pl/sql function in the where clause of a JPA named query?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, plsql

How do I use a pl/sql function in the where clause of a JPA named query?
I am using JPA/Hibernate 5.2.14.  I have a named query like so:

```
        @NamedQuery(name="MyNamedQuery",
                query="SELECT x FROM MyEntity x " +
                        "WHERE x.something = :someParameter " +
                        " AND 1 = my_package.my_function")
```

with the pl/sql function defined like so:

```
create or replace package my_package as
  function my_function return number;
  pragma restrict_references(my_function,wnds,wnps);
end;
create or replace package body my_package as
  function my_function return number is
  begin
    return 1;
  end;
end;
```

When I start up the app, the named query causes errors

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Errors in named queries: 
MyNamedQuery failed because of: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Invalid path: 'my_package.my_function' [SELECT x FROM MyEntity x WHERE x.something = :someParameter AND 1 = my_package.my_function]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:337)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:460)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:892)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:58)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
```

Is there a way I can use my function in the NamedQuery?  I can run the underlying query (replace MyEntity w/the actual table name, etc) in sql/developer just fine.

Answer (score 0):

JPA supports calling of stored procedures and functions since version 2.1. You can find an example [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Advanced_Topics#Stored_Procedures).

Answer (score 0):

The function is not known to hibernate hence the error. Hibernate must be made aware that a function named `my_package.my_function` exists and know what its return type is.

Two possible ways of doing it:

1. Extend the hibernate dialect used and register the function accordingly.
2. Use the `MetadataBuilderContributor` interface to provide information about the function (the recommended option).

A good example is provided at the end of this article, https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-sql-function-jpql-criteria-api-query/